# python spider return empty json file

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I created Json file in python to store scraped data using scrapy , but json file is empty although python scrapy spider scraped all data.i'm trying to store all scraped data into json file.in terminal on crawl command spider display all data but it did not import into json file. i can't find any solution
i'm sharing both files spider and also items.py

i use this command *scrapy crawl scraper -o products.json*

**Spider.py**

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from ..items import ScrapyArbiItem
import requests
from idna import unicode


class Scraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"

    start_urls = [
          'https://www.fenom.com/en/263-men',
        # 'https://www.fenom.com/en/263-men#/page-2',
        # 'https://www.fenom.com/en/263-men#/page-3',
        # 'https://www.fenom.com/en/263-men#/page-4',
        # 'https://www.fenom.com/en/263-men#/page-5',
        # 'https://www.fenom.com/en/263-men#/page-6',
        # 'https://www.fenom.com/en/263-men#/page-7',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = ScrapyArbiItem()

        page_soup = Soup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        uls = page_soup.find_all("ul", class_="product_list grid row")[0]
        # import pdb;
        # pdb.set_trace()
        for li in uls.find_all("li", class_="ajax_block_product block_home col-xs-6 col-sm-4 
        col-md-3"):
            data_to_write = []
            try:
                # print("gnbfrgjrnbgfjnbruigbnruig")
                div = li.find('div', class_='product-container')
                left_block = div.find('div', class_="left-block")
                image_container = left_block.find('div', class_="product-image-container")
                image = image_container.find('a')
                image_url_a = image_container.find('a', class_="product_img_link")
                image_url = image_url_a.find('img', class_='replace-2x img-responsive')
                image_url = image_url.get('src')  # image_url
                url = image.get('href')  # url of product
                right_block = div.find('div', class_="right-block")
                right_a = right_block.find('a')
                product = right_a.find('span', class_="product-name")
                product_name = product.text  # product_name
                pp = right_a.find('span', class_="content_price")
                product_p = pp.find('span', class_="product-price")
                product_price = product_p.text  # product_price


                items ['product_name'] = product_name
                items['product_price'] = product_price
                items['url'] = url


                print(items)
                #print(product_name)
                #print(product_price)
                #print(url)
                #print(image_url)
                next_page = url
                # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
                # print(url)
                # if url:
                #     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parsetwo, dont_filter=True)
            except:
                pass
```

**items.py**

in this file is to arrange all extracted data into temporary containers

```
import scrapy

class ScrapyArbiItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    product_name = scrapy.Field()
    product_price = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you write to file. Also, what's the point of `data_to_write = []`. I don't see anywhere where that's populated

Comment: @chitown88 i removed it . data_to_write = [ ] .you are right i dont use this anywhere . :)

Comment: Ah ok. Ya I see you needed to return the items, which then I’m assuming goes into your function the write to file. I was only pointing out the data_to_write part in case that’s what you were relying on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use  yield(items) instead of  print(items) and it resolve issue.

```
`import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from ..items import ScrapyArbiItem
import requests
from idna import unicode


class Scraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"

    page_number = 2 #for paginatiom

    start_urls = [
          'https://www.fenom.com/en/263-men#/page-1', #firstpage
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = ScrapyArbiItem() #for items container-storing extracted data

        page_soup = Soup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        uls = page_soup.find_all("ul", class_="product_list grid row")[0]

        for li in uls.find_all("li", class_="ajax_block_product block_home col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"):

            try:
                # print("gnbfrgjrnbgfjnbruigbnruig")
                div = li.find('div', class_='product-container')
                left_block = div.find('div', class_="left-block")
                image_container = left_block.find('div', class_="product-image-container")
                image = image_container.find('a')
                image_url_a = image_container.find('a', class_="product_img_link")
                image_url = image_url_a.find('img', class_='replace-2x img-responsive')
                image_url = image_url.get('src')  # image_url
                url = image.get('href')  # url of product
                right_block = div.find('div', class_="right-block")
                right_a = right_block.find('a')
                product = right_a.find('span', class_="product-name")
                product_name = product.text  # product_name
                pp = right_a.find('span', class_="content_price")
                product_p = pp.find('span', class_="product-price")
                product_price = product_p.text  # product_price


                items ['product_name'] = product_name
                items['product_price'] = product_price
                items['url'] = url


                yield (items)
                #print(product_name)
                #print(product_price)
                #print(url)
                #print(image_url)
            except:
                pass`
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you need to do now is return the `items` object and you're good to go.